# Is there a way to see how a GNU SO file is implemented in Linux

Tags: python, linux, gnu

I am getting some weird errors in **linux** and have traced it back to a library. The file is `dfitpack.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. This is a python library that is linked using anaconda.

I want to be able to read this file in a human readable format if possible. Currently I have only found out how to list all the functions inside it with `'nm -D dfitpack.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'`

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Such files mainly contain machine code. Making it "human readable" may be hard, depending on your definition of "human readable". Often these libraries are open source so try to find the source code instead.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical source for the FITPACK library is at https://netlib.org/dierckx/ (there is another similar library at https://netlib.org/fitpack/all ). dfitpack is just the same fitpack library compiled with double precision reals instead of single precision.

They are Fortran procedures, so you need some rudimentary understanding of Fortran to understand them.

Comment: Just to emphasize, the "human readable" version of any binary is the original source code it was compiled from. Understanding their relationship in detail is probably a nontrivial endeavour, and understanding the broader architecture (of the library, and/or the Python integration) is probably a prerequisite for proper understanding.